# MySQL Query a List of Values

Tags: mysql

I want to create a query from a list of values and return data for every match of `cat`.

This works but it's not requiring the `options` value. What's the easier way to query a list of values?

```
SELECT * 
FROM `table1` 
WHERE `option`='R' && `cat`='12' || `cat`='18' || `cat`='30'
```

Answer (score 79, accepted):

You can use the `IN` operator

```
`cat` IN ('12', '18', '30')
```

Comment: Will this be quicker then having 3 individual/seperate queries for `cat`='12', `cat`='18' and `cat`='30'?

Answer (score 6):

You probably forgot to enclose those `OR` parts into parentheses

```
SELECT * 
FROM `table1` 
WHERE `option`='R' and (`cat`='12' or `cat`='18' or `cat`='30')
```