# MySQL Getting last 5 entries for each id in a SELECT - WHERE IN statement

Tags: php, mysql, select, where-in, sql-limit

I would like to select last 5 entries for each of the id in a SELECT - WHERE IN statement.

```
//How to get last 5 entries for each id
SELECT * FROM table1
WHERE id IN (111,222,333,.....)
ORDER BY date DESC
LIMIT 5
```

EDIT: Example of how data structure

```
id  date    name
111 7-Nov   Anna
111 8-Nov   Belle
111 9-Nov   Mary
111 10-Nov  John
111 11-Nov  Robert
111 12-Nov  Gary
111 13-Nov  Rick
222 8-Apr   Sarah
222 9-Apr   Lee
222 10-Apr  Margaret
222 11-Apr  Lisa
222 12-Apr  Will
222 13-Apr  Alex
222 14-Apr  Kelly
222 15-Apr  Lucas
```

Desired results

```
id  date    name
111 13-Nov  Rick
111 12-Nov  Gary
111 11-Nov  Robert
111 10-Nov  John
111 9-Nov   Mary
222 15-Apr  Lucas
222 14-Apr  Kelly
222 13-Apr  Alex
222 12-Apr  Will
222 11-Apr  Lisa
```

I am not sure this can be done in mysql. I have tried looking at some answers posted and I can't find the answers.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8945538/mysql-query-a-list-of-values

Comment: @MarcoMura I am trying to get last 5 entries for each id (inside the where - in statement) now all the entries.

Comment: Consider providing proper DDLs and the desired result

Comment: You are unclear. we need data structure

Comment: consider using union ...

Comment: why do you want to use a `WHERE IN()` statement when you want to get the last 5 entries? in your example you have to know the ids for the `IN()` condition - so you have to know the last 5 ids which you want to get. that doesn't make any sense.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129693/using-limit-within-group-by-to-get-n-results-per-group

Answer (score 0):

It just pseudo code, but I think it works. try this

> SELECT
>
> id,
>
> SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT( some_column_1 ORDER BY date DESC),',',5)
>
> SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT( some_column_2 ORDER BY date DESC),',',5)
>
> ....
>
> FROM table WHERE id IN (111,222,333,.....) GROUP BY id;

it look not like you want. I just showing how use GROUP_CONCAT and SUBSTRING_INDEX function, you apply this, you can find answer.

Answer (score 0):

this doesn't make much sense, but if your mysql-version supports it, you can do it with a subquery:

```
SELECT * FROM `table1`
WHERE `id` IN (SELECT `id` FROM `table1` ORDER BY `date` DESC LIMIT 5)
```